# Wi-Fi disconnects after sleep - no power management tab in driver configurations

Tags: power-management, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I am using windows 10, and for some reason probably after last update (didn't noticed exact time) Wi-Fi started to disconnects after sleep. It may still stay connected to the router ("connected, no internet") and then I run troubleshooter and it reconnects, or it can be totally disconnected from the router and I need to connect again.

from quick web search it seems that the most common solution is go to power management tab in Wi-Fi adapter configurations, but unfortunately its missing, also in advanced power settings in the windows settings I have no wireless options so I can tell it to stay on no matter what.

Pictures of my settings:

[Advanced power settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs4Xw.png)

[Wi-Fi adapter properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSVth.png)

Does some one have another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Set to Maximum Performance in Advanced Windows Power Management under Wireless.  Also after un-suspending, wait 2 or 3 minutes and see if wireless enables itself. Restart after making any changes in Advanced Power Management

Comment: @John added pictures in questions. unfortunately I don't have that option.

Comment: The Picture does not show all the advanced setting so it is not clear.  Look also in Settings, System, Power and Sleep and Settings, Internet, Wireless to see if settings drifted there for your particular computer. Also ask the Manufacturer's support line.